# TFS build server - Shared Projects build error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I've recently added some shared projects to my existing Visual Studio solution and now the build process on our TFS build server fails.

[Project Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDIoL.png)

Our build server was able to build the previous version of the solution and is again after the rollback.
My shared projects are referenced like that in the .csproj files. (Created via Visual Studio)

```
  <Import Project="..\xxx\yyy.projitems" Label="Shared" />
```

The build works fine with Visual Studio and the command line, but on the TFS build server it fails with this error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (187): "DestinationFiles" refers to 1 item(s), and "SourceFiles" refers to 2 item(s). They must have the same number of items.

When executing the msbuild command via cmd, everything works fine. Also on the same maschine as the build server is running on.
On the command line it looks like that:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /nologo "xxx.sln" /m:1 /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: We have TFS 2015 Update 2

Comment: What's the build system you use? vNext or XAML? Can you share the detailed steps so that we can try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: And did you use "Copy" task in your project file? If yes, can you share the content?

Comment: XAML, It fails after getting the sources and running the RunMSBuild-Task.

In de Xaml it is: <mtba:RunMSBuild CleanBuild="[CleanBuild]"  ....

No, we have no copy task. I have only added the shared project.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue if creating a new solution and adding a shared project to it? I cannot reproduce it at my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly I was not able to get the project running on our build and tfs server. But it works properly with Visual Studio Online and the new build system. Maybe upgrading to the latest TFS version would bring the same result.

Answer (score 0):

1. On your build agent machine, find the source folder that your build agent get resources, and use MSBuild command line to build the project in the source folder to check the result.
2. Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`.
3. Clean the Cache folder on Server machine. The folder path is: `C:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache` (TFS 2015)
4. Re-add all assemblies.

Comment: The MSBuild command still works in the command line.
The cache folders have been cleared but it still has the same error.

Comment: Do you also add the argument /nologo "xxx.sln" /m:1 /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform="Any CPU" in your build definition?

Comment: It were not exactly the same. I've tried to call it with the same parameters (like /deployOnBuild) but it still works on the command line.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side. I've tested in my TFS 2015.3 + VS 2015.3, by adding a Shared Project to an existing project, and adding the reference in the .csproj file, the build still pass. You may compare your environment with mine and upgrade yours to see whether the issue persists. Also, you may try to configure a new build agent to see whether you would reproduce this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not the privileges to upgrade our tfs. I will try to get the permission to test it within visual studio team services, to find out whether it is a problem of our older versions.

Comment: You may create a new light project and add a Shared Project to see whether you can reproduce this issue. In this way, you can clarify the issue is from your environment or project.